# When you’re close vs when you’re close up

Tags: difference

- And when you're **close up**, give me the shivers - the song Shivers by Ed Sheeran
- And when you’re **close**, give me the shivers - my made up example

I’m wondering if there’s any difference between **close up** and **close** and if switching one with the other would make any difference.

Comment: The bare meaning is pretty much the same. The effect in a song might be quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Close up" is synonymous to "right next to" or  "right in front".
"Close" is synonymous to "near" or "nearby".

Examples:

"He was close up to the television" means he was only inches away.

"He was close to the television" means he wasn't far from it but most likely a foot or two away.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference. "Up" (whether your want to call it an adverb, verb particle, etc.) is used with the adjective "close" only in certain circumstances. For example, if a runner was nearing the end of a marathon, then I could say that he or she was "close" to the finish line but not "close up". However, if a person stood directly in front of me, then I could say that the person was standing either "close" or "close up". Otherwise, the meanings of both expressions are basically the same.

The best way to know when you can use "close up", or course, is to listen to and read a lot of English. If you're wondering about which expression to use, then you can just default to "close", because it should always work.